# Execute commands from stdin to stdout without print statement like in REPL

Tags: python, command-line

What's the easiest way to make this work:

```
> echo 1+1 | [run python in REPL and exit with capturing all statement values to stdout ]
2
```

Yes, we can do `echo "print(1+1)" | python` but that requires to write `print`. The point is to make python behave like PowerShell:

```
> echo 1+1 | powershell -c -
2
```

Yes, we can do `echo 1+1 | python -i` but that output some noise (python version etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The following is not a recommended practice, since it uses the unsafe `eval` function. However, in the context of what you are asking for, where you seem to have control of all the steps in the process, it will do.

Write the following simple Python program (`my_program.py`):

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write(str(eval(sys.stdin.read())))
```

Then, use:

```
> echo 1+1 | python my_program.py
2
```